# WCF WebHttp Service using POCO from EntityFramework 4.1 - dbContext

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, dbcontext, webhttp

I am trying to return a POCO in WCF WebHttp Service.  I am using EntityFramework 4.1 and generating the The entity is created entities using the DbContext Generator.

All works well with the EF.  I can query the database and work with the entities.  The problem comes from my WebHttp service.  When I try to return a list of these entities, I get Error 324 (empty response) and when I try to return a single entity object, I get the WCF error - "Request Error".  The service help page looks fine and sample responses are fine.

I tested the services by returning only the firstname of the entity changing the return type of the services to List and string.  This works fine.

I assumed (having looked at a [tutorial on WCF WebHttp Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/07/getting-started-with-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx)) that there is no need to add  [Serialize()] or other attributes to the entities.

I am lost as you why the service will not return an entity.

Thanks for any/all help.
ROB

Here is the code for the service...

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class SearchService
{

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Students")]
    public List<coop_Students> GetStudents()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        CottageDataEntities db = new CottageDataEntities();
        var students = from s in db.coop_Students
                       where s.status == "enrolled"
                       orderby s.lastname, s.firstname
                       select s;
        return students.ToList();

    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Echo/{text}")]
    public string Echo(string text)
    {
        return "Hello " + text;
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Students/{studentID}")]
    public coop_Students GetStudent(string studentID)
    {
        using (CottageDataEntities db = new CottageDataEntities())
        {
            int id = int.Parse(studentID);
            var student = db.coop_Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.studentID == id);
            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up using T4 Templates to force your EF to generate the Entities in a POCO manner. Give your self a little more control.

Comment: After enabling tracing, I found the problem was that the objects were dynamic proxies of the actual entities, WCF threw an exception because the object did not *exactly match* the type in the method signature.  Disabling proxy creation works.

    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Downside is the lost of related entities (access through navigation properties).  The resulting object simply includes a boolean saying that there is a related entity.  

I can live with "flat" objects in this project but does anyone know of a solution that would also return related entities?

Comment: Yeah you don't want WCF to send Navigation Properties those can cause cyclical references and go on forever and it will try and send all related fields.